# imprecate - Direct or Indirect Transitive?

Tags: prepositions, difference

Does [imprecate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/imprecate) admit of a direct or indirect object or both? What prepositions must be used?
Examples of prepositions don't exhaust, and the Google Books contains *against*, not mentioned on OED.

This is a rare verb, yet there are instances of both uses:

[Direct](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22imprecated%20him%22&btnG=Chercher%20des%20livres&tbm=bks&tbo=1&hl=fr&gws_rd=ssl#hl=fr&q=%22imprecate%20%20him%22&tbm=bks) object:

[Indirect](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22imprecated%20him%22&btnG=Chercher%20des%20livres&tbm=bks&tbo=1&hl=fr&gws_rd=ssl#hl=fr&q=%22imprecate%20against%20him%22&tbm=bks) object:

Source: P184, How the Law Works, Gary Slapper

Answer (score 1):

The OED cites examples of absolute or intransitive use of the verb **imprecate**, from the 17th century, now obsolete.

In your citation, the man who used the obsolete intransitive form of imprecate is a medical doctor writing a treatise on the Four Gospels in 1853.  Consider, is such a man likely to have his hand on the pulse of the living language?

:-)

[image]

Comment: Anybody who can write a diatesseron is pretty knowledgeable - about something.

Answer (score 0):

1 ... with her dying breath the witch imprecated the villagers for their relentless persecution of her. Transitive use, meaning to wish evil upon someone, to curse someone.

2 to imprecate something upon someone. Transitive use.

A rare verb. It seems still in use in AmE, whereas it is considered archaic in BrE.
Longman Dic. Of Contemporary English has not registered this verb.